# REGEXP Bases Replace not working in MySQL Procedure

Tags: mysql, regex, stored-procedures, replace, prepared-statement

I have a set of keywords I want to change in a column on a table wherever they occur. So there is a main table and the keywords table which has 2 columns: the keyword to find and what to change it to. So for instance, there is a row for

findtxt    repltxt
 LTD$      LIMITED

I then have a procedure with the important parts quoted as follows:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT findtxt,repltxt FROM keywords ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
SET done = 0;
OPEN cur1;

myLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO ftxt,rtxt;      
    IF done = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE igmLoop; 
    END IF;
    SET @t1 = CONCAT('UPDATE ',tbl,' SET ',sanecol,' = REPLACE(',sanecol,',?,','?) WHERE ',sanecol,' REGEXP ?'); 

    PREPARE stmt FROM @t1;

    SET @ftxt = ftxt;
    SET @rtxt = rtxt;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @ftxt,@rtxt,@ftxt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END LOOP myLoop;
CLOSE cur1;
```

sanecol and tbl are passed in as parameters into the procedure representing the column to change and the table having the column.

This procedure runs looping through all records (I know because it takes a while) but ends with no errors. Yet the keywords are not changed (e.g. LTD does not become LIMITED.)

What am I doing wrong?

I have tested to isolate the problem by

```
SET @t2 = CONCAT('UPDATE ',tbl,' SET idd = 1 WHERE ',sanecol,' REGEXP ?');
```

Where idd is just a test flag created to be sure the REGEXP is working. IT is indeed by setting the idd column for each record with LIM  or LTD  to 1.

So the issue is really with the this part of the code:

```
CONCAT('UPDATE ',tbl,' SET ',sanecol,' = REPLACE(',sanecol,',?,','?)
```

The REPLACE is just not working.

[image]

Sample data in the table to replace

```
id        replacecol
1         FOREVER UNITED LTD
2         APPLE DEVICES LIMITED
3         QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIM
4         FINANCIAL TIMES LTD
```

This should change to:

```
id        replacecol
1         FOREVER UNITED LIMITED
2         APPLE DEVICES LIMITED
3         QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIMITED
4         FINANCIAL TIMES LIMITED
```

Comment: I suspect that your underlying problem is that you are storing the keywords as a delimited list, rather in a table with one row per keyword.

Comment: it's in a table: i've edited to add a screenshot.

Comment: What do you think will happen a name like 'BEAUTI SLIM'?  Perhaps 'BEAUTI SLIMITED'?

Comment: Those will be ignored because there is a blank space before LIM$ and LTD$ In the keywords table. I'm ok with that treatment for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `keywords`, `to_replace`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `to_replace` (
    ->  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->  `text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
    ->  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->  `regexptxt` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->  `findtxt` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->  `repltxt` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `to_replace` (`text`)
    ->  VALUES ('LTD$ AAAA'),
    ->         ('BBBB LIM$'),
    ->         ('AAAA LTD$ LIM$ BBBB'),
    ->         ('FOREVER UNITED LTD'),
    ->         ('APPLE DEVICES LIMITED'),
    ->         ('QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIM'),
    ->         ('FINANCIAL TIMES LTD'),
    ->         ('BEAUTI SLIM'),
    ->         ('FINANCIAL TIMES LTD & FOREVER UNITED LTD'),
    ->         ('FOREVER UNITED LTD & QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIM');
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `keywords`
    ->    (`regexptxt`, `findtxt`, repltxt)
    ->  VALUES
    ->    (' LTD$', 'LTD', 'LIMITED'),
    ->    (' LIM$', 'LIM', 'LIMITED');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(`tbl` VARCHAR(64), `sanecol` VARCHAR(64))
    ->  BEGIN
    ->    DECLARE `done` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    ->    DECLARE `retxt`, `ftxt`, `rtxt` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    ->  
    ->    DECLARE `cur1` CURSOR FOR
    ->    SELECT `regexptxt`, `findtxt`, `repltxt`
    ->    FROM `keywords`;
    ->  
    ->    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` := TRUE;
    ->  
    ->    OPEN `cur1`;
    ->  
    ->    `myLoop`: LOOP
    ->      FETCH `cur1` INTO `retxt`, `ftxt`, `rtxt`;
    ->      IF `done` THEN
    ->        CLOSE `cur1`;
    ->        LEAVE `myLoop`;
    ->      END IF;
    ->  
    ->      SET @`t1` = CONCAT('UPDATE `', `tbl`,'`
    '>                          SET `', `sanecol`, '` = REPLACE(`', `sanecol`, '`, ?, ?)
    '>                          WHERE `', `sanecol`, '` REGEXP ?');
    ->      PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`t1`;
    ->      SET @`ftxt` = `ftxt`,
    ->          @`rtxt` = `rtxt`,
    ->          @`retxt` = `retxt`;
    ->      EXECUTE `stmt` USING @`ftxt`, @`rtxt`, @`retxt`;
    ->      DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    ->    END LOOP `myLoop`;
    ->  END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT `id`, `text`
    ->  FROM `to_replace`;
+----+-------------------------------------------+
| id | text                                      |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | LTD$ AAAA                                 |
|  2 | BBBB LIM$                                 |
|  3 | AAAA LTD$ LIM$ BBBB                       |
|  4 | FOREVER UNITED LTD                        |
|  5 | APPLE DEVICES LIMITED                     |
|  6 | QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIM                      |
|  7 | FINANCIAL TIMES LTD                       |
|  8 | BEAUTI SLIM                               |
|  9 | FINANCIAL TIMES LTD & FOREVER UNITED LTD  |
| 10 | FOREVER UNITED LTD & QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIM |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`('to_replace', 'text');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `text`
    ->  FROM `to_replace`;
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | text                                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | LTD$ AAAA                                        |
|  2 | BBBB LIM$                                        |
|  3 | AAAA LTD$ LIM$ BBBB                              |
|  4 | FOREVER UNITED LIMITED                           |
|  5 | APPLE DEVICES LIMITED                            |
|  6 | QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIMITED                         |
|  7 | FINANCIAL TIMES LIMITED                          |
|  8 | BEAUTI SLIM                                      |
|  9 | FINANCIAL TIMES LIMITED & FOREVER UNITED LIMITED |
| 10 | FOREVER UNITED LTD & QUICKFIX DESIGNS LIMITED    |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try but I see an obvious misconception. The `to_replace` table will not contain those values literally. The sanecol column has company names which are written in an inconsistent manner e.g.records could have MYCOMPANY LTD, HISCOMPANY LIMITED, THEIRCOMPANY LIM. The $ in the regexp is to isolate when LIM and LTD appear at the end of the field. This procedure is thus supposed to take a generic REGEX description from the `findtxt` column of `keywords` table and replace with a uniform spelling gotten from the corresponding `repltxt` column.There will be no $ in the col

Comment: @user1729972: Can you add some real sample data and how do you expect the final result?.

Comment: HI I added sample data by editing the original post. It's at the bottom.

Comment: The problem is definitely with the REPLACE ...?...? part. I've added some info on troubleshooting just carried out

Comment: @user1729972: Updated answer. It may not be the answer you expect, but it can help you get your final solution.

Comment: Awesome: separating the REGEX match string from the string to find was the clincher!